# Substitution Theorem on "A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by W. Rautenberg

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, substitution

I'm trying to understand the Substitution Theorem (Theorem 3.5, page 71) in "A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by W. [Rautenberg](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/raut/logic3/announce.pdf). At some point Rautenberg states: "The reader should recall the definition of $(\forall x\alpha)^\sigma$ page 60 and realize that the induction hypothesis refers to an arbitrary global substitution $\tau$". Why $\tau$ is arbitrary? Shouldn't the induction hypothesis be $\mathscr{M}_x^a\vDash\alpha^\sigma$ $\iff(\mathscr{M}^\sigma)_x^a\vDash\alpha$? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

What we are trying to prove is :

> $\mathscr{M} \vDash \varphi^\sigma \ \iff \ \mathscr{M}^\sigma \vDash \varphi$.

Thus, when unpacking $\mathscr{M} \vDash \forall x \alpha^\tau$ to  $\mathscr{M}_x^a \vDash \alpha^\tau, \text { for all } a$, we have to "move" $\tau$ from the formula to the model, according to the induction hypotheses :

> $(\mathscr{M}_x^a)^{\tau} \vDash \alpha, \text { for all } a$

The hypotheses is : "and $σ$ a *global substitution* [whatever]" and $\tau$ (as defined in the clause of page 60) is again a *global* one.

---

The key point is the def of $(\mathscr{M})^{\sigma}$ [top page 71] : $\sigma$ is an operation of *symbols* of the language.

Thus, applying it to $\mathscr{M} := (\mathscr{A}, w)$ menas to apply it to $w$, because the structure $\mathscr{A}$ is made of "objects" and not of symbols.

Thus, $(\mathscr{M})^{\sigma} := (\mathscr{A}, w^{\sigma})$, where in turn : $x^{w^{\sigma}}= (x^{\sigma})^{\mathscr{M}}$.

---

---

*Long comment*

It is harder to formalize the result than describe it with words...

Consider a simple example in the language of *arithmetic*, with $0$ and $1$ as individual constants, and let $(x=0)$ the formula $\varphi$.

Consider the usual structure $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and let $0^{\mathbb{N}}$ denotes the number $0$ and the same for $1^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Finally, let $w : \text {Var} \to \mathbb N$ a *valuation* such that : $w(x)=0^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $w(y)=1^{\mathbb{N}}$, and let $\mathscr{M} := (\mathbb{N}, w)$.

We have $\mathscr{M} \vDash (x=0)$.

Consider now the substitution $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(x)=y$.

Clearly : $\text {not-}(\mathscr{M} \vDash (x=0)^{\sigma})$.

Regarding the **Substitution theorem**, the above example is enough to show the [quite obvious] fact that :

> $\text {not-}(\mathscr{M} \vDash \varphi^\sigma \ \iff \ \mathscr{M} \vDash \varphi)$.

The theorem states that,

> > regarding the relation of *satisfaction* $\vDash$ between a formula and a model,  the syntactical operation of *substitution* appied to formulas commutes with the same operation applied to *valuations*.